# Memory management problems when saving an infinite list to a JSON file in Python without calling print()

Tags: python, memory

I am not able to python list in json file without calling print function

I was creating an infinite list and when I tried to put list of generated numbers in a json file, it returned an prime.json file but it was empty. So I tried to print the list and it successfully started dumping data in json file. I think it has to do something with memory management but I am not able to understand it.

```
import json

num = 5
primes = [2, 3]

while True:
    for i in primes:
        if num % i ==0:
            break

        if i == primes[-1]:
            primes.append(num)

            #if i delete below print(primes) then why prime.json beomes empty
            print(primes)
            filename = 'prime.json'
            with open(filename, 'w') as f:
                json.dump(primes, f)

    num = num + 2
```

Comment: Where is `i` defined? Also it's unclear/nonsensical what you mean by "memory management problems" since Python is garbage collected.

Comment: You aren't creating an infinite list. You are creating an infinite series of finite lists, each one a prefix of the primes. You repeatedly replace the contents of `prime.json` with the most recently created prefix list. When do you *stop* generating such lists? (Also, this is very inefficient; given the simple structure of the desired JSON, I would simply one the file *once*, write `[` immediately, then append `f'{num},'` to the file each time you find a new prime number. When you stop generating primes, then write `]` and close the file.)

Comment: However you are terminating the code, you are doing so after `primes.json` has been truncated by opening it but before `json.dump`is able to finish writing anything to it.